# Saving button's enable disable state and getting this last state on create

Tags: sharedpreferences, state

I'm newbie in android and I'm trying to develop some applications. But last two weeks I've been stuck in this code. In short, I have two buttons in a layout. These buttons are Add and delete button. If I clicked the add button, add will be disabled and delete will be enabled. Or if I clicked the delete, delete will be disabled add will be enabled. I want to save state of these two buttons (which one is clicked) and get the last clicked state on create. But the problem is it's not working. When I open the app both buttons are show disable state. Or not saving either. Never working.

```
public class UserVideoInfoActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2;
    SharedPreferences preferences2;

    Button buttonadd;
    Button buttondelete;


    private static final String ADD = "ADD_KEY";
    private final static String DELETE = "DELETE_KEY";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_video_info_layout_2);

        buttonadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonaddlayout);
        buttondelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondeletelayout);




        preferences = getSharedPreferences(ADD, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences2 = getSharedPreferences(DELETE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        buttonadd.setEnabled(GetState());

        buttondelete.setEnabled(GetState2());



        buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
                buttondelete.setEnabled(true);

                SaveState(buttonadd.isEnabled());


            }
        });

        buttondelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
                buttondelete.setEnabled(false);

                SaveState2(buttondelete.isEnabled());


            }
        });


    }

    private void SaveState(boolean isChecked) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(ADD, isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void SaveState2(boolean isChecked2) {
        editor2 = preferences2.edit();
        editor2.putBoolean(DELETE, isChecked2);
        editor2.commit();
    }


    public boolean GetState() {
        return preferences.getBoolean(ADD, false );

    }


    public boolean GetState2() {
        return preferences2.getBoolean(DELETE, false);
    }

}
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondeletelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="delete" />
```

Comment: is preference object null?

Comment: can you include the full error?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. This code is not giving null pointer exception. All buttons are always showing  disabled on create. Never enabling.

Comment: If i delete these two code lines buttons are  enabling  on create. These codes are for getting last state of the activity. Add or delete is clicked state ------                                                                                                                                      
                                                                  
                                                              
                                                              
       buttonadd.setEnabled(GetState());
       buttondelete.setEnabled(GetState2());

Comment: This change is enabling the buttons. But still not saving. if i click the add , add button turns disable and Delete button enable.  If i clicked the delete vice versa. Problem is not saving. Not giving the last state of this click state.